# My intent give me nothing 

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Selected.class);
```

Main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
  myIntent.putExtra("NAME", "yeah");

when i want to retrieve the "yeah" in my other class it doesn't work :

```
    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    String myIntentString = icicle !=null? icicle.getString("NAME"):null;
    if(myIntentString==null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        myIntentString = extras != null ? extras.getString("NAME") : "nothing passed in";

    }
        test.setText(myIntentString);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have the order inverted on putting the extra and starting the activity.

```
myIntent.putExtra("NAME", "yeah");
Main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included ".Selected" in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes but i think i'm gonna invert the order like the other answer.